# Make directory available locally in Docker

Tags: docker

I have a directory in my Docker container, and I'm trying to make it available locally using `-v screenshots:/srv/screenshots` in my docker run command but it's not available.

Do I need to add something else to my command?

Comment: when you share a volume, it shares from the `host` to the `container`, then you can modify the content from the `container` and it will be updated in the `host`.

Comment: Ah ok, so if my code is creating directories in the container, but not in the host, is there a way for me to access those directories locally?

Comment: So you want to mount your host screenshots folder into your containers /srv/screenshots? If your host volume already contains data it will "overlay" the data in the container and only new files will show up in your host

Comment: Ah what about the other way around? I have a directory in my container but I can't see it locally. Is there a way for me to access it locally?

Comment: check that: https://youtu.be/YFl2mCHdv24?t=8m21s

Answer (score 0):

Host volumes are mapped from the host into the container, not the other way around. This is one way to have persistent storage (so the data don't disappear when the container is re-created).

You can copy the screenshot folder to your host with `docker cp` and map them in.

You will have your screenshots in the local `screenshots` folder. Mapping them in with `-v screenshots:/srv/screenshots` makes them appear in `/srv/screenshots` in the container, but these files are really on the host.

See: [Mount a host directory as data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)